# Genymotion no funciona en AMD con Windows 10

Tags: android, windows10, genymotion

He estado un tiempo utilizando Genymotion en mi ordenador pero con problemas, a veces funcionaba otras veces no, me lo he reinstalado muchas veces y ahora ya definitivamente no me funciona.

El error exacto es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo que activar la Virtualization en la BIOS, pero NO TENGO ESA OPCION, mi portatil es un Acer Aspire 5560G, con AMD A8

Me gustaría saber como puedo utilizar Genymotion o que necesito instalarme al no tener la opción de Virtualización en AMD.

Llame a Acer y me dijeron que mi ordenador no tiene la opcion de Virtualizacion... Aunque yo he podido usar alguna vez Genymotion con Windows 10 y creo que alguna actualizacion hizo que me fallase

Comment: puedes detectar que accion realizas cuando se presenta el problema ? inicias alguna aplicaicon en concreto, realizas alguna operacion sobre el emulador? o es algo aleatorio.   No creo que sea un problema de AMD o Win10, quizas solo sea un bug del emulador, no evaluaste contactar al soporte para plantear el problema https://www.genymotion.com/contact/ , o quizas plantearlo en un foro especifico sobre este soft https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/genymotion-users  Pero deberias mencionar si hay algun mensaje de error.

Comment: El error es unable to load VirtualBox engine, dice que tengo que activar la Virtualization en la BIOS, pero no tengo esa opcion...

Comment: que modelo de AMD tiene a pc ? por lo visto estos emuladores usan virtualizacion por eso requiere. Si ingresas al BIOS no visualizas alguna opcion similar a la de esta imagen http://i.stack.imgur.com/ncxPz.jpg  Sino esta la opcion quizas debas actualizar el BIOS de la pc

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta para que reflejes tu problema concreto. Tal como luce, suena como si fueses a un doctor y le dijeras "'me duele la cabeza, qué hago?" y esperas que el doctor mágicamente sepa si tienes fiebre, migraña, un tumor o sólo es que te ha caido una pelota hace unos minutos. Mientras más descripción des de tu problema, será más fácil proveerte ayuda y que otros lectores se beneficien de la pregunta y las posibles respuestas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si bien la respuesta le falta plantear en la respuesta veras que comenta el fallo que recibe, tiene que habilitar la virtualizacion de la pc para que funcione VirtualBox que es lo que usa el emulador, el problema parece ser que la pc no tiene esa caracteristica

Comment: @LeandroTuttini  esta información debe estar en la pregunta, no en los comentarios. La pregunta de por sí debe describir el problema y la situación. Imagina como otros usuarios interactúan en el sitio, sobretodo aquellos que no tienen cuenta en el sitio: leerán la pregunta directamente e irán a las respuestas, luego a los comentarios. Esto tiene base en que lees primero el texto con letras más grandes y luego el texto en letras más pequeñas.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza imagine que dirias eso por esi edite la pregunta, agregando esta data que estaba en los comentarios

Comment: Actualizado, disculpad la falta de informacion

Comment: Según las especificaciones de tu portatil que he visto [aquí](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Acer-Aspire-5560G-Series.59388.0.html) tiene un procesador `AMD A8-3500M` que según [esta página](http://www.notebookcheck.net/AMD-A-Series-A8-3500M-Notebook-Processor.55755.0.html) si que tiene las extensiones `AMD-V`. Comprueba la información que aparece en el administrador de tareas que te comento en mi respuesta y si puedes compartir el archivo de logs, que menciona en el error, se podrá ver más detalles del error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que deberías hacer es **comprobar si tienes activado el soporte para virtualización**.

La forma mas sencilla de hacerlo en **Windows** 10 es desde la pestaña de **Rendimiento** del **Administrador de tareas**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra forma de comprobarlo es usando la herramienta [Microsoft Hyper-V System Compatibility Check](http://api.viglink.com/api/click?format=go&jsonp=vglnk_145556111386810&key=633d6a967658f9951e260a5805d9f349&libId=ikob4rjv010113au000DA161kxhqgmwhq6&loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.itworld.com%2Farticle%2F2981515%2Fvirtualization%2Fvirtualbox-diagnose-and-fix-vt-xamd-v-hardware-acceleration-errors.html&v=1&out=http%3A%2F%2Fsupport.amd.com%2Fen-us%2Fsearch%2Futilities%3Fk%3Dvirtualization&title=Fix%20VirtualBox%20%27VT-x%2FAMD-V%20hardware%20acceleration%27%20errors&txt=support%20page)

En caso de que estas herramientas indiquen que está habilitado, el problema podría ser que tengas instalado Hyper-V. En ese caso tendrías dos opciones, desinstalarlo o cambiar la configuración de inicio para poder arrancar con Hyper-V deshabilitado ([este](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SwitchEasilyBetweenVirtualBoxAndHyperVWithABCDEditBootEntryInWindows81.aspx) artículo en inglés es muy bueno)

Si nada de esto te funciona **es posible que tu procesador/placa no soporte las extensiones de virtualización** o, que aunque las soporte exista algún problema y tengasque actualizar la bios. En [este](http://www.itworld.com/article/2981515/virtualization/virtualbox-diagnose-and-fix-vt-xamd-v-hardware-acceleration-errors.html) otro artículo (en ingés) puedes ver más información pero cada placa tiene sus propias herramientas para actualizar la bios y tendrías que buscarlas en la web del fabricante

**Actualización:** El error también podría estar relacionado con la configuración de los interfaces de red que se crean en Virtual Box, mírate [este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEmfUxwQUgY) vídeo

Comment: Tras leerme varios articulos, he leido que en W10 Home no deja virtualizar, se ha de tener un windows pro, enterprise o ultimate, los programas que comprueban la compatibilidad de AMD -V me dice que no se puede acceder a dicha informacion y no reconoce la tarjeta grafica (el programa que checkea la virtualizacion) he visto que mi portatil soporta AMD-V, ya que esta automaticamente puesto en modo on, en la bios sigo sin tener la opcion despues de virtualizarla... Gracias por la ayuda ofrecida! Probare en Ubuntu

Comment: @M.Mariscal No hay de que. Me estañaba que un protatil relativamente nuevo no tuviese las extensiones de virtualización, aunque sea Acer y AMD ;-)   Lo de que W10 Home no deja virtualizar no tenía ni idea, yo uso Profesional. Suerte con Ubuntu, seguro que ahí Virtual Box funcionará a las mil maravillas

Answer (score 1):

Para activar la virtualización de la bios deberías tener 2 cosas en cuenta.

1- Una opción en la BIOS del PC que se llama "AMD SVM Support" que debe estar habilitada.

2- Un servicio de Win 10 debe estar deshabilitado "Hyper V"

Si tu BIOS no permite habilitar dicha opción deberías considerar actualizar la BIOS para poder hacerlo.

Saludos
Emiliano